# assigning values to variables inside an array

Tags: arrays, ruby, assign

coming from PHP so I'm sorry if the question is too easy for yall :/

My code looks like

```
animals = [
  "horse" => "Caballo",
  "Dog" => "Perro",
  "Cat" => "Gato",
  "Hawk" => "Halcon"
]


puts animals[2]
```

but is not working it aint printing anything on the terminal ... I don't know if this is the right way to do it in ruby or not :/

what I'm trying to do is to reference individual values for example:

Horse in spanish is animals['horse']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `{}` to define a hash then:

```
animals = {
  "horse" => "Caballo",
  "Dog"   => "Perro",
  "Cat"   => "Gato",
  "Hawk"  => "Halcon"
}

puts animals["horse"]
#Caballo
```

Comment: omg :( I did spend like 40 minutes trying to find the solution. Thank you :D